# changing parameter of a function successively from an array in python

Tags: arrays, function

The code used is:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[4,3,2,1]

def func(x,y):
    return x+y

func(x,y)
```

Now while calling a function, I can call using single elements, each from x and y array. e.g. `func(1,4)`. Instead of doing it for every element, how can I change parameter set (x,y) from array above for successive set?

Note: The elements to be entered from an array as parameters are: (1,4),(2,3),(3,2) and (4,1).

I need to change this set successively.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question with your expected output.

Comment: Next time you ask the question specifically for *Python*, please provide that tag as well. Otherwise, entire community gets this question, even those who have purposefully ignored to see the question about *Python*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dot(a, b):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
    total += a[i] * b[i]
    return total
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.